# Convert a groupByKey to reduceByKey

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I read that `reducebyKey` is a better option on large datasets to reduce shuffles of the data and, in this way, enhance performance.

I am trying to convert my use of `groupByKey`. First it has to be converted to rdd as:

```
val linksNew = links.map(convertToRelationship)
  .flatMap(bidirRelationship)
```

links is a dataset and dataset api doesn't have `reduceByKey`. What is the equivalent of `.groupByKey(_._1)` when using `reduceByKey`?

```
val linksfinal = linksNew.rdd.reduceByKey(???)
```

Actual code:

```
val biLinks = links
  .map(convertToRelationship)
  .flatMap(bidirRelationship)
  .groupByKey(_._1)
  .reduceGroups((left, right) => combineBidirerRelationships(left,right))
  .map(_._2._2)
```

Schema of the dataset, just before using the `groupByKey(_._1)`:

[image]

Some of the actual data in the dataset:

[image]

Comment: How does your data look like before the `groupByKey()`?

Comment: @Shaido like so `DataSet(String, Relationship)` and then should be as after 
 with groupByKey follows, `KeyValueGroupedDataSet[String, (String, Relationship)]`

Comment: Added an answer that I believe will work, although I didn't test it, tell me how it works out.

Comment: @Shaido added a picture,

these two added,`col1: String, col2: Relationship` when i printed the schema of what we are trying to convert, they are `struct1` and `struct2`, for example struct2 is a data of Relationship case class created

Comment: Could you add the output of `show()` as well?

Comment: @Shaido, picture of show to object before groupByKey, struct2, or _2 is a case class object,

Comment: Made some changes to the code and tested it when using case classes. Should hopefully work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is more efficient or not, however, it should be possible to convert to `reduceByKey` since you perform a `reduceGroups` directly after the `groupByKey`. Short example using part of the provided code:

```
val biLinks = links
  .map(convertToRelationship)
  .flatMap(bidirRelationship)
  .rdd
  .map{row => (row.getAs[String](0), row.getAs[Relationship](1))} // See explanation below 
  .reduceByKey((left, right) => combineBidirerRelationships(left, right))
  .map(_._2._2)
```

Depending on how the dataframe looks like after using `.rdd`, an additional conversion could be required. When converting from a dataframe the resulting rdd will be a `RDD[Row]`. However, for `reduceByKey()` to work a tuple rdd of type `RDD[(A,B)]` is required, where `A` and `B` are the types (they could also be tuples themselves).

---

Short example of how the `rdd.map(...)` conversion can work with `structs`:

```
case class Relationship(a: Long, b: Long)
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq((1, Relationship(3L, 2L)), (2, Relationship(20L, 7L)))).toDF()
val rdd = df.rdd.map{ row => (row.getAs[String](0), row.getAs[Relationship](1))}
```

This gives the required tuple rdd type, here `RDD[(String, Relationship)]`.

Comment: these two added,`col1: String, col2: Relationship`

when i printed the schema of what we are trying to convert, they are struct1 and striuct2, for example struct2 is a data of Relationship case class created?

Answer (score 1):

> I read that reducebyKey is a better option on large datasets to reduce shuffle and or shuffles on reduce side, and enhance performance.

It is not. You are confusing "old" RDD API where `groupByKey` has different semantics.

In `Dataset` API `groupByKey` + `reduceGroups` uses similar execution model as `reduceByKey` in the old API. In fact conversion to RDD uses less efficient shuffle mechanism and is very costly, so you're just making it worse.